# Javascript regex to select import statements in react project

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to search for the import statements of npm packages, but not the local imports,

for eg:
I want to search for these types of strings:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import ApolloLinkTimeout from 'apollo-link-timeout';
import { RestLink } from 'apollo-link-rest';
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client';
import { ApolloLink } from 'apollo-link';
import { onError } from 'apollo-link-error';
```

but NOT these:

```
import { getAllAccounts } from '../../store/actions/actions';
import { CREATE_ACCOUNT_QUERY } from '../queries/AccountsQuery';
import UserContext from '../UserContext';
```

is this possible using Regex or any other way in javascript
I have tried
`import {[^}]*}.*'foo-bar'`
but this is not working as expected.

**Edit**:
as per the comments,

```
^import\s+(?:\{\s*\w+\s*\}|\w+)\s+from\s+['"]([^\/]+?)['"];?$
```

is working better, but not for the following cases:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Col, Modal, ModalHeader, Row } from 'reactstrap';
import { useLazyQuery } from '@apollo/react-hooks';
```

Comment: So you want to check which packages are used and which ones are not?

Comment: @ArtyomVancyan yes, basically a list of all npm packages imported (excluding the local imported files)

Comment: Maybe a tool like `npm-check` would help?

Comment: @JoaoJesus i don't have package.json file in the project

Comment: What about just look into `package.json`. The `dependencies` node contains all the installed packages

Comment: @Jaood_xD as i mentioned i don't have package.json file

Comment: Try [`^import\s+(?:\{\s*\w+\s*\}|\w+)\s+from\s+['"]([^\/]+?)['"];?$`](https://regex101.com/r/PwzGi8/1)

Comment: @ArtyomVancyan updated the question, please check, it is working, but not for some cases.

Comment: Check this [`^import\s.*?\sfrom\s+['"](@[\w\/\-]+|[^\/]+?)['"];?$`](https://regex101.com/r/31dEQb/1)

Comment: @ArtyomVancyan yes, this is working perfectly, thanks. i will try to study how this is working, can you please add this as an answer and if possible explain how this is working, that would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^import\s.*?\sfrom\s+['"](@[\w\/\-]+|[^.]+?)(?:\/.*?)?['"];?$
```

##### Explanation

- `^` Start of a string
- `import\s.*?\s` Match string that starts with `import` keyword then module default or exports after a space character till to `from`
- `from\s+` Match `from` keyword and one or more spaces
- `['"]` Match `'` (single quote) or `"` (double quote) characters
- `(` Capturing group

  - `@[\w\/\-]+` Package name should start with `@` and can contain word characters (letters, numbers, underscore), `/` and `-` characters
  - `|` Or
  - `[^.]+?` Package name should contain any character except `.` (dot)
- `)` Close group
- `(?:\/.*?)?` Match package subpaths without capturing (this can exist or not)
- `['"];?` Match close quote and optional `;` at the end
- `$` End of a string

See the regex [demo](https://regex101.com/r/31dEQb/2) and please attention to the last line, it captures only the package name.